# Linux environment variables referencing other variables

Tags: linux, environment-variables, boot

I am using a boot script from a network vendor, I am using this on RedHat 7.2  The start script sets up the environment with several variables, however I don't think these variables are set-up correctly.

I have added the start-up script to /etc/environment and I can see that the variables are defined and available to all users.

This is an example of how the variables are defined in the script:

```
    export V1=/opt/nameofsupplier/sdk/CentOS-RHEL-7-x86_64
    export V2=${V1}/lib/cam
```

There are many more, if I try this from a terminal:

```
    cd $V1
```

It works fine, however if I try:

```
    cd $V2
```

I get:

```
    base: cd $V1/lib/cam: No such file or directory
```

The path is valid, and if I do this in the shell:

```
    export V2=${V1}/lib/cam
    cd $V2
```

It works without any error, how do I fix the script?

Comment: do you see them if you check the output of `env`? Check `env | grep ^V`

Comment: Yes, they are all present.

Comment: and what value do they have? Do you see `V2=${V1}/lib/cam` or `V2=/opt/nameofsupplier/sdk/CentOS-RHEL-7-x86_64/lib/cam`? Also check if `echo "$V2"` works

Comment: They have the variables embedded in the others.

Comment: /etc/environment is not interpreted by a shell.
It's a set literal `key=value` lines. You can't reference other variables in it nor run scripts from it.
If you want to launch a script on every login, use /etc/profile.

Comment: @PSkocik, excellent, thank you that's fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be right in suspecting an ill-definition of these variables.
`/etc/environment` can only contain variable definitions - it is not executed like a normal script (see its documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables), which says *Variable expansion does not work in /etc/environment.*), so no variable expansion of V1 in the definition of V2 takes place. Therefore V2 is not correctly defined.
Try to source `/etc/environment` lines in the system-wide `/etc/profile` (or its equivalent, depending on the shells of your users) or in specific users' `~/.profile`s.
As the last resort you can just plain copy the respective  lines of `/etc/environment` to the above mentioned scripts (but this will make it harder to maintain).
You could also correct the definitions in `/etc/environment` not to rely on expansion, i.e. like this:

```
export V2=/opt/nameofsupplier/sdk/CentOS-RHEL-7-x86_64/lib/cam
```

(assuming there are not too much of them to be corrected). But this will also be hard to maintain.

Comment: That was the problem, moving the content into /etc/profile has resolved this issue.